# How to add a separator to a listBox from code AND cast it to not selectable

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, separator

[image]

This is what I do and it works:

```
 if (condition...)
 {
   ComboBoxItem cbi2 = new ComboBoxItem();
   cbi2.Content = new TextBox() { Background= Brushes.Red, HorizontalAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, Margin=new Thickness(0) , Height = 5, IsHitTestVisible=false, BorderBrush=null};
   ibw.cmbOptions.Items.Add(cbi2);
 }
```

the only problem is that the textBox despite not being IsHitTestVisible is selectable and that is a problem. So I'm open also to totally different solution. The only constraint is to act from code.

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use the `Separator` element?

Comment: That was my first idea but it didn't appeared so I thought it was not meant to be used in this context

Comment: The `Separator` should not be wrapped in a `ComboBoxItem`. If you do that, it doesnt appear. Just adding a `Separator` works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 options here:

First, simply use the `Separator` element:

```
ibw.cmbOptions.Items.Add(new Separator());
```

---

Or, you could disable the `ComboBoxItem`, which would make it non-selectable for the `ComboBox`.

```
ComboBoxItem cbi2 = new ComboBoxItem();
cbi2.IsEnabled = false;
cbi2.Content = new TextBox() { Background= Brushes.Red, HorizontalAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, Margin=new Thickness(0) , Height = 5, IsHitTestVisible=false, BorderBrush=null};
ibw.cmbOptions.Items.Add(cbi2);
```

Comment: Solution 2 doesn't work since it adds a not-enabled item to the combox. Had already tried this.

Comment: Solution 1 works as you said like a charm. Solution 2 as I said add a not enabled (kind of make grayer textbox) and that is selectable addable to the combobox. But solution 1 is enough for me. Thanx!!!!